# Data redaction by oracle

Tags: oracle

In my current project i have a challenge regarding data redaction. we do not get data from Client  because they have sensitive information in some of the columns. So to get the data from them we decided to encrypt the data and then it will come to us.

I am struggling to find an inbuilt algorithm in oracle which encrypt the data. One of the main objective of mine is:
1.) Length of my original input should remain the same after data redaction.
2.) Data type of my original input should remain after data redaction.

Can you please give me your input to achieve this.

Thanks and Regards
Ankit.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Typically, users who ask questions here have already tried something and can provide a [mcve]. It sounds like you may have started something. You should edit the question to add your attempt as you will have a better chance of getting responses. Otherwise, your question is currently too broad/off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

There are various options to encrypt your data, you can build your own PLSQL procedures using the DBMS_CRYPTO builtin package.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_crypto.htm#ARPLS65670

Or if you use Enterprise Edition of oracle:

transparent data encryption:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e40393/asotrans.htm#ASOAG600

and if you have 12c, you can use Oracle Data Redaction:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/database/data-redaction-odb12c-2331480.html

The advantage of the last one is that the data is not touched inside the database, Oracle Data Redaction acts as an upper layer masking data on the fly before it is returned to the application.